# Teams in Role Based Access Control model

Tags: architecture, permissions, rbac

We need to modify an existing application's RBAC model to introduce the concept of Teams. Currently we have the option to create new roles based on a permission set and assign multiple roles to users. The idea of Team is to have hierarchy as per the roles. Say we have four roles :

1. Investor
2. Manager
3. Team Lead
4. Engineer

A Team can have any number of users from among all these roles. So there can be 2 Investors, 4 Managers, 2 Team Leads and 6 Engineers. We have to run our business logic according to the roles in the team.

As per my understanding this requires us to fix the number of roles, because if we don't know which kind of roles users are creating then we can not run our desired business logic in the teams. However, I feel that restricting the roles and applying authorization checks based on roles is not a good approach. What would be better approach in this scenario?

Comment: What does your application take into consideration - role, permissions or the team?

Comment: It takes Permissions in to consideration. If we allow custom roles then user will be able to set random permissions which will contradict team roles. Either I'll have to add permissions like "CanBeManager" or "CanLeadTeam" and then do permission based checks or go with the only limited Default roles.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your lowest common denominator is permission. So I would go by Permissions. Allow/deny/restrict based on permissions. A Role would have one to many permissions. A User depending on your model can have one or many roles. And teams are just tags.